# And an optional Pinch of salt

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm big and round but not a plate,
>
> My components could tell you more,
>
> Learn what I am you need not wait,
>
> If you can solve my riddles four.

1)

> I open wide for fire's light,
>
> A well placed treasure hides within,
>
> Take this freely I invite,
>
> Plundered by those who can gold spin.

2)

> Treasure within I also hide,
>
> A floating viscus golden gel,
>
> Not concerned with what's outside,
>
> Behind a wall of thinnest shell.

3)

> Pale colour and container both,
>
> A silky comforting dew,
>
> Perfect fuel for youngling growth,
>
> Each drop a pearl of nature's brew.

4)

> Fourth, a product of the third,
>
> More treasure - pale and golden bar,
>
> Absent so much whey and curd,
>
> Now mix well all you've solved so far.

What am I (Yes "hungry" but what else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are:

> A pancake

Because:

> A pancake is big and round but not a plate

My components could tell you more:

> The other riddles are the ingredients of a pancake:
>  1. Flour  (Made from a grain, which opens in the light. I think the reference to spinning gold is the story of *Rumplestiltskin* in which a miller's daughter could spin gold from straw.)
>  2. Egg  (the yolk is golden and viscous, behind a shell)
>  3. Milk  ("fuel" or food for young children)
>  4. Butter (a product of milk, for frying)

And of course:

> An optional pinch of salt.

Comment: Spot on, but I was being a bit naughty with #1 (Rot13: Sybhe = Sybjre naq "Gnxr guvf serryl V vaivgr, Cyhaqrerq ol gubfr jub pna tbyq fcva" vf ersreevat gb orrf jub cyhaqre gur sybjre'f 'gernfher' naq znxr ubarl.)

Comment: @BrentHackers Interesting! Would you prefer that I edit my answer to match, or are you happy that my answer fits?

Comment: I don't mind one bit.  Your answer should include your thought process, not mine.